# using TTL to drive LED

Tags: transistors, led, amplifier

I have a TTL signal of 1 V, and I need to drive an LED by amplifying the TTL to 3 V. I used the following voltage amplifier circuit with Rc = 10 KOhm and Re = 1 kOhm. The DC input I use is 3 V. However the LED does not light up. Does anybody have a better idea for a configuration that might work?
[image]

Comment: What is generating the 1 V? How much current can it source/sink? You want 3 V. I get that. But how much current do you want for the LED in this case? What low impedance voltage sources do you have available?

Comment: Just use an  inverter ---- TTL or bipolar transistor.

Comment: 1 volt is not a valid TTL output level.  What is producing this voltage, and/or what load do you have on a TTL logic output?

Answer (score 1):

please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNNz94.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You need to connect up the LED like this. When the input goes high the LED will light. The R1 value may need adjusting depending upon just how much current it takes to light your LED.

Comment: R1 should be 50Ω max if red, orange or yellow.  5Ω if blue, green or white.

Comment: @Misunderstood - Your comment may be correct for some LEDs. But your statement is incorrect for other LEDs. I have a project right now that has 64 red LEDs that are biased from a 3.3V supply and have 2.2K series resistors and are plenty bright enough.

Comment: Plenty bright enough for what?  Growing plants?  Architectural lighting?  Emergency vehicles?  Aircraft obstruction lights?  Mine may be correct for only some?  Do you think 500 µA is typical?  On the other hand I rarely drive an LED with less than 350 mA.   So 10-20 mA is a good starting point especially when dealing with the unknown.   I was just trying to help, not step on your toes. .

Comment: @Misunderstood - My posting already has included the statement "The R1 value may need adjusting depending upon just how much current it takes to light your LED" so there was really no need for much additional clarification.  Your second comment even more illustrates why your first comment was probably not best stated.

Comment: My point was "plenty bright" is subjective.   With a 330Ω resistor there are many LEDs that will not light up at all. I use high power LEDs that look dead below 10 mA.  If the OP's LED is blue, green, or white it will likely not work at all with a 3V supply minus the transistor's CE voltage.  Your circuit will not work at all for many LEDs and using a 330 Ω resistor will increase the number of LEDs that will not work.   Yes, I did see your comment "R1 value may need adjusting".  You do understand your 330Ω resistor will probably give, even a red LED, only about 500µA?